# Using the Google Search Console API to test if a site is mobile friendly is failing with 400 errors

Tags: google-api

I want to check if a website is "mobile friendly" using the google api to access their own testing service.

I am using curl via PHP to talk to the https://searchconsole.googleapis.com/v1/urlTestingTools/mobileFriendlyTest:run end point.    Ref google api docs [here](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api/v1/getting-started#curl-usage).

However the returned data from my code is always a 400 error page.[image]

What I do know is that my API key is valid. If I run the command via the curl utility in a linux shell it works (ref the example given in the google documentation).

Has anyone seen this before ?   It must be something to do with my php code and how I've implemented curl in it...

```
$ch = curl_init();
$curlConfig = array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => "https://searchconsole.googleapis.com/v1/urlTestingTools/mobileFriendlyTest:run?key=xxxx",
    CURLOPT_POST           => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array('Content-Type:application/json'),
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => json_encode(array(
        'url' => 'https://www.test.com'
    ))
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

So with the help of someone [outside](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/webmasters/PR3NAnFHz68/5jJ7odrsCAAJ) of SO I got an answer to this which was basically to setup to rewrite the code slightly differently.  I can't work out what exactly is the sticking point but it works if formatted as follows...

```
$data="http://www.yourdomain.com/";
$url="https://searchconsole.googleapis.com/v1/urlTestingTools/mobileFriendlyTest:run?key=xxxxx";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$payload = json_encode( array( "url"=> $data ) );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST"); 
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$api_content = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

$api_result = json_decode($api_content);

var_dump($api_result);
```